# ASP.NET Temporary files taking up too much space

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, iis, asp.net, disk-space-utilization

I have approximately 900 applications running on the server where each one points to a folder that contains content that is about 215MB in size.

When I noticed that my server's hard drive was almost full, I did a scan with WinDirStat and found the `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files` folder to be 300gb in size.

In the base of that folder, I have one folder for each application I have, which is normal I imagine.  However, under this I have many folders that look to be different hashes:

```
\Temporary ASP.NET Files
    \myapplication1
        \11482199
        \5c2d65f6
        \ ... (10 more)
    \myapplication2
        \f7e1646c
        \ ... (4 more)
```

When I inspect the various folders some look to be from years back.

My typical workflow when I deploy a new version is I create a new folder with the web files, and then I will point an existing IIS application to the new folder.  I am wondering if that is what is causing my artifacts above.

Currently to mitigate the issue I am deleting the older files manually, I can also create a script to do so, but to me it seems to be a fragile solution to something that shouldn't even be a problem to begin with.

Why is my temporary ASP.NET folder growing wildly?  It seems ASP.NET is not managing it properly.  Is there an expectation that I should be monitoring this (even though it's in the Windows folder)?

Comment: `The software I am hosting is leveraging ASP.NET dynamic compilation`.  I'm not sure that 'leveraging' is an accurate description, but you crystallized one of the main reasons why pre-compiling is useful.

Comment: Sorry @GregAskew I used the wrong terminology,  my MVC views are compiled dynamically, my applications binaries are pre-compiled by our build server.  I have updated the question to remove this.

Comment: Given the large number of applications and some of data is old, I'm not seeing this as a problem.  You could probably implement a one-line computer startup script that clears out the folder on each restart to prevent the accumulation.